# ObservableCollection - binding to HierarchicalDataTemplate shows type

Tags: c#, binding, treeview

I am trying to create a simple logging system with a hierarchical 'feel'. I hope this screen shot explains my object clearly:

[image]

As you can see, I create a new object of type LogDetails which exposes just 4 fields:

```
public string Message;
        public LogStatus Status;
        public string ErrorDetails;

        public enum LogStatus
        {
            Complete, Failed, Error, FatalError, Progress, Started
        }
```

I have another class which has a Title property (string) and a LogDetails property.

When I bind to XAML, my tree view shows this:

[image]

As you can see, the root is fine and expected/desired (red) but each sub category isn't broken down - I want to be able to bypass a level and go direct to ErrorDetails, Message and Status. So, I would like to create this (mocked up in Word, but hopefully you get the idea):

[image]

This is my xaml:

```
<Grid>
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding LogDetailsList}" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>

            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>            
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
</Grid>
```

And my MainWindow code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        static public ObservableCollection<Log> logList;

        public MainWindow(List<Log> logs)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            logList = new ObservableCollection<Log>();

            foreach (var item in logs)
            {
                logList.Add(item);    
            }

            this.DataContext = logList;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction, or at least let me know if my design is flawed?

**EDIT**
When I try to add another text block or ItemTEmplate, I get the error message "The property ItemTemplate is set more than once" or "The property VisualTree is set more than once"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide a path to the binding expression.